# HDMI connection: RGB vs YCbCr

Tags: video, graphics-card, display, hdmi, colors

When connecting GT 640M graphics card (on a laptop) with Dell SE2419HR 23.8" screen, there is a huge difference when switching to **YCbCr** mode. Black becomes blackish, the text is rendered in a sharp manner and color palette seems rather natural.

I haven't found much information on the Internet what is the difference between RGB/YCbCr modes. Is it possible that my HDMI cable has some deficiency or it's just that laptop graphics card and this particular screen are best compatible at YCbCr mode?

Any references to explore deeper into the subject are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should only need YCbCr for "TV pictures" & RGB for the rest; however you would appear to be running into calibration issues, which really are going to need a hardware colorimeter to correctly address. If you don't care about actual colour accuracy, pick whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Have the same concern: RGB should suit PC source the best. But it's obviously not working correctly.

Comment: You need to calibrate. That's the only real solution. Whether you try to do that by eye or do it properly with a colorimeter is up to you & your finances. A decent colorimeter will set you back $£€ 250 or so. What you're finding at the moment is that one looks 'blacker' than the other, probably higher contrast. You have no real way of knowing which is actually right, or what else might be out of kilter - but unless you work in graphics or video then it doesn't actually matter, so long as you accept what you see is unlikely to be what anyone else sees on the same image.